Generating a continuous sine wave using I2S on STM32
I am able to generate a sine wave "burst" using I2S on a STM32 microcontroller (Chinese version:PUYA PYF32F403, almost identical to STM32F407).   I have followed examples on the Web such as the one here:
https://github.com/afiskon/stm32-i2s-examples/blob/master/sine-wave-example/Src/main.c
However, the sine wave output comes in bursts, and the length of a burst is proportional to the length of the array, not surprisingly. That gives me only a fraction of a second worth of sine wave. The call being made in the above example is
res = HAL_I2S_Transmit(&hi2s2, (uint16_t*)signal, nsamples, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
This is a blocking call. Therefore my question is, can the use of this blocking call give me a continuous sine wave tone? If not, can someone point me to a good example of non-blocking code that can help me get to a continuous sine wave?

You can have an array of samples and set the DMA channel in circular mode to automatically loop through the array endlessly.
The only problem is that the data must fit into memory, so if you want to have 1 kHz sine wave at 48 kHz rate, your loop is 48 samples, but if you want to have 997 Hz sine wave, your loop is 48000 samples.

The DMA buffer can remain constant if you continuously fill one half with new data. Use the circular interrupts for this.
